# List of 3D Numpy Arrays to Array Conversion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm using Image from PIL, to open images and load them into numpy arrays of dimension(300,300,3). These arrays are appended to a list, I then want to convert this list into a numpy array. Everything that **should** work, hasn't. I keep getting the weird error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (300, 300, 3) into shape (300, 300)
```

Here is a small example code:

- before loop

```py
training_data = []
```

- in loop

```py
image = Image.open(path).resize((300,300),Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

```py
training_data.append(np.asarray(image))
```

- outside loop

```py
training_data = np.array(training_data)
```

the simple Issue is that I get the error talked about above. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have collected a list of arrays of different sizes, perhaps some are b/w and others are color:

```
In [17]: alist = []                                                                                  
In [18]: alist.append(np.ones((300,300)))        # bw                                                            
In [19]: alist.append(np.ones((300,300,3)))      # color                                               
In [20]: np.array(alist)                                                                             
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  #!/usr/bin/python3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-7512d762195a> in <module>
----> 1 np.array(alist)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (300,300,3) into shape (300,300)
```

`v1.19` gives us a warning when we try to make a array from arrays that differ in shape.  Sometimes that still gives us an object dtype array, but with this combination of shapes, the result is your error.

===

An equivalent way of combining the arrays into one is with `np.stack`.  If it works the result is the same; if not, the error is different:

```
In [21]: np.stack(alist)                                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-724d9c1d0554> in <module>
----> 1 np.stack(alist)

<__array_function__ internals> in stack(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in stack(arrays, axis, out)
    425     shapes = {arr.shape for arr in arrays}
    426     if len(shapes) != 1:
--> 427         raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')
    428 
    429     result_ndim = arrays[0].ndim + 1

ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

Comment: Reading your answer, I decided to pull all the shape data into a file to look over the shapes, and I have found 100% consistent shapes between all elements of the list.

Comment: You could try `np.stack(training_data)`.